# error reading .po file in java

Tags: java, gnu, po

i read a bit about reading from .po files and i still have some questions. Does anyone know if you can directly read from a .po file just like reading from a .properties file in java, or does it need to be transformed from .po to .properties?

I imported the class GettextResource and :

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("stuff.po.I18n");
System.out.println(GettextResource.gettext(rb, "name_test"));
```

Where 
msgid "name_test"
msgstr "test" (from .po file)

This does return only the string "name_test".
I clearly have no clue what i am doing here...
any thoughts will be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635721/is-there-a-java-library-for-parsing-gettext-po-files

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/javadoc2/gnu/gettext/GettextResource.html

> To compile GNU gettext message catalogs into Java ResourceBundle
>   classes, the msgfmt program can be used.

Have you used this utility to convert your .po file to a resource bundle that can be read by getBundle?